# Did the Dutch eat their Prime Minister?

Tags: political-history, sources, netherlands, rebellion

According to this [article](https://www.historyextra.com/period/stuart/is-it-true-that-an-angry-mob-of-dutchmen-killed-and-ate-their-own-prime-minister-in-1672/) an angry—*one might add hungry*—Dutch mob feasted on the mutilated remains of their ‘Grand Pensionary’ (i.e. Prime Minister) De Witt and his brother:

---

> There are accounts of some among the mob taking parts of the bodies,
> and eating them. One man is even said to have eaten an eyeball.

---

What primary source(s) documents these gruesome ***accounts***?

Comment: Once! Once, you kill and eat your prime minister, and you never hear the end of it.

Comment: [Hangry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hangry)?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Maps/comments/q17syj/countries_who_diddid_not_eat_their_prime_minister/

Comment: The bigger question is, did each member of the mob simultaneously say ***"Lekker!"*** and wave a hand next to one of their ears at the same time?

Comment: that's why you only need to do it once for future PMs to take notice @Peter

Answer (score 48):

#### Yes, we *(possibly)* ate him, but not because of hunger

It happend in 1672, known in Dutch history as the '[rampjaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampjaar)' or Year of Disaster. The Dutch republic was attacked by an alliance of France, England and (the Bishop of) Munster at the same time. The Republic was on the brink of defeat.

The prime minister, known then as [Raadspensionaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_pensionary), was [Johan de Witt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_de_Witt). His brother [Cornelis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelis_de_Witt) was minister of defense. The Republic had *(past tense)* another person of power, the Prince of Orange, his official position was hereditary stadtholder. At that time the prince was a young man, and the office of stadtholder was abolished.

He would later become [William III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England), king of England, but at that moment he was 22 years and barely adult. He didn't hold any official power, apart from his royal title, **not** Stadtholder. The Republic was going through the [First Stadtholderless Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Stadtholderless_Period). The prince was looking for a way to gain power. And he found it...

In Dutch politics of the time there were two parties: The Orange party and the Staten (States) party. Usually the business elite and coastal provinces were Staten, the population and the army Orange. The Staten party was usually moderate and more liberal, the Orange party was more strict and Calvinist.

The Staten party was firmly against war and in favor of appeasement. War is bad for business, after all. Johan de Witt blundered by not preparing for war. His intelligence was faulty, and he thought he could solve any issue diplomatically.

The combined attack of France, England and Munster came as a rude surprise. French and Munster troops occupied large parts of the country. The people panicked. They *(with some encouragement of supporters of the Prince)* wanted a strong man to solve this crisis, and most of all: anyone else in charge than Johan the Witt and his brother.

Under immense political pressure Johan de Witt stepped down, and his brother also resigned. However, this was not enough. His policy of appeasement looked very much like treason. He was widely seen as a spy of France, or bought by the French king.

His brother Cornelis was arrested for treason, locked up in [The Gevangenpoort](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevangenpoort_(Den_Haag)), and interrogated under torture. While he was recuperating (in that prison) his brother Johan visited him. The charges were debatable, even then, and questioning under torture was definitely unusual.

Then, mysteriously, a mistake was made. The prison was under guard by the militia ([schutterij](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutterij)), mainly to protect the brothers the Witt from being lynched. At a certain moment the old guard withdrew, while the new guard detachement wasn't there yet. How could this happen? Someone must have made a dreadful mistake scheduling! That meant the prison was unguarded, with only the Witt brothers present.

The mob (lower class citizens of The Hague) didn't wait, stormed the prison, captured the brothers, and tore them to pieces. Literally. Some parts were eaten indeed. Not over a barbecue with some sauce, but bites out of body parts. Raw, in other words, during the frenzy.

**There certainly was no feasting. Though the people were hungry indeed, there was no widespread starvation or cannibalism. The documents in the comments from @Njuffa indicate there was no cannibalism. If someone did eat parts of the bodies, it was to spite the victims; to insult and humiliate them.**

Afterwards, the prince very much regretted the whole affair. He shed some crocodile tears, and was very very sorry. After he gained full control of the government, that is. Nobody was convicted. The whole affair was hushed up.

From @Njuffa:

- Historisch Verhaal en Politique Bedenckingen Aengaende de Bestieringe van Staet- en Oorloghsaken, voor-gevallen onder de Bedieningen van de Heeren Cornelis en Johan de Witt. Amsterdam: J.H.B. 1677, [pp. 618-628](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Historische_verhael_en_politique_bedenck/7tplAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA618&printsec=frontcover)
- [Gedenkwaerdige Stukken](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gedenkwaerdige_stukken_wegens_den_moordt/hYZjAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=needen&pg=PP3&printsec=frontcover), wegens den moordt der Heeren Cornelis en Johan de Witt

**Funny side note:** This is all common stuff most Dutch know about. Perhaps not in this much detail, but it's common knowledge. A few months ago a blog published a cartoon with the face of Mark Rutte, at that time the prime minister, next to a portrait of Johan de Witt. With the caption: *Mark, remember. We ate the the last prime minister we didn't like!*

Comment: From a first perusal, the account given in *Historisch Verhaal en Politique Bedenckingen Aengaende de Bestieringe van Staet- en Oorloghsaken, voor-gevallen onder de Bedieningen van de Heeren Cornelis en Johan de Witt.* Amsterdam: J.H.B. 1677, [pp. 618-628](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Historische_verhael_en_politique_bedenck/7tplAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA618&printsec=frontcover) does not mention body parts being eaten. The brothers were shot and run through with a sword, the bodies stripped naked and hung up-side down at the execution place, and some fingers cut off the *Pensionaris*.

Comment: Some eyewitness (?) accounts were collected in: *Gedenkwaerdige Stukken, wegens den moordt der Heeren Cornelis en Johan de Witt,* an anonymous [publication](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gedenkwaerdige_stukken_wegens_den_moordt/hYZjAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=needen&pg=PP3&printsec=frontcover) that is tentatively dated to 1676 in the literature. On p. 14 one can read that various body parts were cut off the corpses: "En wierden verder de lighamen van alle hare ledematen ontbloot, een ieder een genoeghsam bekent, den een afsnijdende de vingers, duymen, teenen, neus, handen, ooren, enz."

Comment: On p. 22 of *Gedankwaerdige Stuken* it is mentioned that someone cut a strip of flesh from the corpse of Cornelis, and announced he was going to fry and eat it, but it is not known whether he followed through: "Eenen onbeschaemder als de andere, meynde de Ruaerds mannelyckheyt af te beten me sijne tanden, dogh het selve te tay sijnde, sneed het af. Een ader nam sigh oogh uyt de hooft, slockende het selfe in, vragende luyts keels, of hy he wel soo weder soude kunnen ouytkacken. Een ander ... sneet den Ruaerd een stuck vlees uyt het lyff omtrend sijn heupen ... te gaen braaden ende te eeten:"

Comment: If you are fluent in Dutch (your user name *suggests* you might be) you might want to review the two historical publications that I linked in my comments above. I can read Dutch but only with elementary school level proficiency. In addition to that I am struggling with the old-fashioned spelling and some outdated vocabulary.

Comment: @njuffa I am Dutch, are (reasonably) fluent in it and will do that. I feel your pain, I can read - with some difficulty - Middelnederlands. We Dutch have grammar, so we can change the spelling. Just about every day of the week. :-)

Comment: please, pretty please, a link to the cartoon with Rutte

Comment: Am I wrong that njuffa's sources don't back up the claim that "Some parts were eaten [...] raw"?

Comment: @benrg No, he counters that claim. I agree with him. The popular narrative is that some people ate the PM. I never believed that. Sure, they might take a bite during the frenzy, and probably spit it out, but that is not eating him. History Extra infers that clearly. It was a very brutal lynching.

Comment: I fear you may be overestimating the quality of Dutch history education if you think most Dutch know about this.

Comment: "War is bad for business, after all." `[Citation needed]`" Have you checked out what happened to the US economy during WWII? Of course, we only suffered one direct attack, as opposed to being the main battleground... Also, "mainly to protect the brothers _the_ Witt" - I'm sure that's supposed to be "brothers _de_ Witt", but not enough rep to make such a small change.

Comment: It wasn't William of Orange but Willem III who became king of England. As in, Willem III of the Dutch republic, not of England. Also, why 'stadtholder'? The mix of German 'stadt' and English 'holder' makes no sense.

Comment: @paddotk In English, "William of Orange" commonly refers to Stadthouder Willem III, who was [King William III of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England) and King William II of Scotland. The translation ["stadtholder"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadtholder) for "stadthouder" is also standard usage - translating titles without a direct equivalent is hard, and at some point that semi-translation seems to have stuck, in the same way we say ["Bayern Munich"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Bayern_Munich) rather than "Bayern München" or "Bavaria Munich".

Comment: @IMSoP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Silent#:~:text=%5B4%5D%20as-,William%20of%20Orange,-(Dutch%3A%20Willem Perhaps the William III Wikipedia page isn't on point with this. But I've never heard of William III being referred to as William of Orange.

Comment: @paddotk I just searched "William of Orange" on DuckDuckGo and clicked some results on the first page; plenty refer to William III of England: [1](https://www.history.com/topics/european-history/glorious-revolution#william-of-orange), [2](https://www.orangeheritage.co.uk/william-legacy), [3](https://www.worldhistory.org/William_III_of_England/), [4](https://www.yourirish.com/history/17th-century/william-of-orange-invades-england), [5](https://www.undiscoveredscotland.co.uk/usbiography/monarchs/williamiii.html), [6](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofEngland/William-Of-Orange/)

Comment: @paddotk It's worth noting that if you just search "William of Orange" on Wikipedia, you get a page stating that _both_ people are commonly called that in English. There's apparently been [a lot of debate about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:William_of_Orange), but skimming through, I don't see anyone arguing that it should _only_ refer (*in English*) to Stadthouder Willem I, even if that's who it would normally refer to *in Dutch*.

Comment: and now of course the De Witts have become much more respected, to the point that there have been (maybe still are) major Navy ships named after them.

Comment: @jwenting I think that our PM's who were murdered were among the best we had: Johan van Oldenbarneveld, the de Witt brothers, *possibly* Pim Fortuyn.

Comment: @Jos didn't want to get into good or bad, as that becomes a matter of personal opinion and political ideology very quickly. Fortuyn was indeed murdered but of course no PM.